# UserProfileService GetUserProfile Modified Date in 2010

Tags: 2010, list, powershell

I have a problem when loading a `UserProfile` from the `UserProfileService` in `Powershell`. I am able to get a list of properties, however I can't seem to find when the profile was last modified.

One property that appears close is `CurrentChangeToken` however for all of my user profiles it is `1;28208;03/18/2014 02:00:00` which is a few hours before I ran the script.

```
$siteUrl = "http://intranet/"
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext($site)
$pm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

$allUsers = Get-SPUser -Web $siteUrl
$allUsers = $allUsers | Where-Object { $_.UserLogin -like "*DOMAIN*" }
$resultsArray =@()

foreach($user in $allUsers)
{    
    if($pm.UserExists($user.UserLogin))
    {
        $userProfile = $pm.GetUserProfile($user.UserLogin)
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the last modified date of each User Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the profile modified date by using `LastContentModifiedDate` userprofile property. Please check the same property in the PowerShell code.

Here is sample code in server object model:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("siteurl"))
{                       
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
    foreach (var profile in profileManager)
    {
        userName = ((Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile) (profile)).AccountName.ToString().Split('\\')[1];

        if ((((Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile)(profile)).PersonalSite != null))
        {
            DateTime profileModifiedDate = ((Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile)(profile)).PersonalSite.LastContentModifiedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personal Site just returns the MySite of the user. It does not help you retrieve the User Profile information.
Please check in FIM (missclient), there you have a lot of info.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this to list the last date the user changed the profile. I created this script using info i found on the internet including this page so thanks everyone ;-).

```
$siteUrl = "http://profilesite/"
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext($site)
$pm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$changes = $pm.GetChanges()
$result = @{}
$count = 0
foreach($change in $changes)
{
    if($result.ContainsKey($change.accountname))
    {
        $result.Set_Item($change.accountname,$change.eventtime)
    }
    else
    {
        $result.add($change.accountname , $change.eventtime)
    }
    $count = $count + 1
}
$result
$count
```